# Databricks spark-csv check for empty file

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, databricks

I'm trying to read in a TSV file into a DataFrame object with the following code:

```
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(javaSparkContext);
Map<String, String> sqlContextOptions = new HashMap<>();
sqlContextOptions.put("header", "true");
sqlContextOptions.put("delimiter", "\t");
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .options(sqlContextOptions)
        .load(path);
```

Right now, the code throws an UnsupportedOperationException if it encounters an empty file. I want to handle empty files, but I don't want to assume that this exception will always mean an empty file. What is the best practice for checking if the given file is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `path` explicitly defined, but I'm assuming it's a String containing the path to a file. If that's the case, you could open it in a `BufferedReader` object and check if you can read from it.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));     
if (br.readLine() == null) {
    // handle empty file...
} else {
    //do something...
}
```

Comment: So, you have to manually check the file first? That's a shame. It feels that something like empty file checking should have been built in.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know of any other way.  I checked the newer functions in Java 8 but there isn't anything (as far as I came across) that would automatically check.